Is the Democratic Convention bound by the primary results?
The Democratic primaries resulted in a large majority of "pledged delegates" for Joe Biden to the Democratic National Convention in August 2024.
I could not find a conclusive answer to the question whether those "pledged" candidates are in fact — in spite of their "pledge" — free to vote as they please in case there is a competing candidate. If so, what meaning would "pledged" actually carry?
This scenario is brought up as a way to arrive at a different Democratic Presidential candidate in case Biden refuses to withdraw his candidacy.

They are not legally bound to vote for the candidate that they are pledged to but it is generally expected that they will vote for that candidate in the first round.
Here's everything you need to know about the Democratic delegate process

Pledged delegates are the ones allocated to presidential candidates
based on the vote. The delegates themselves are real people, elected
to pledge support to the candidate to whom the delegates are allocated
to. While it may seem contradictory to the name, these delegates are
not legally bound to support any candidate, but, they are presumed to
be loyal to the candidate they were elected to support – and the
presidential campaigns work hard to ensure the delegates elected to go
the convention are ardent supporters of that respective candidate.
There are 3,979 pledged delegates this cycle.

There was a recent rule change that only allows for pledged delegates to vote in the first round unless certain conditions are met

The rules changed after last cycle, and only pledged delegates are
able to vote on the first ballot at the convention, unless a candidate
has won enough pledged delegates that automatic delegates couldn't
change the outcome of the vote if they were also allowed to
participate. A candidate would have to secure at least 2,375.5 pledged
delegates this cycle in order for automatic delegates to vote on the
first ballot.

If someone gets enough pledged votes before the convention they are considered the presumptive nominee which is why people want Biden to drop out

Securing the nomination before the convention will happen if a
candidate wins an outright majority of pledged delegates, or if a
candidate builds an insurmountable lead, and the remaining major
candidates drop out. That person would then be the "presumptive
nominee" – but they wouldn't actually become the nominee until the
convention itself, where a roll call of delegates will take place.

If no one wins the nomination on the first round the rules change a lot which allow pledged delegates to change their votes

If no one secures a majority of pledged delegates through the
Democratic primary process, there could be a contested convention that
would require multiple ballots to determine the nominee – something
that has not happened since 1952. The rules on a second ballot and
beyond are slightly different. If a nominee isn't secured on the first
ballot at the convention, "superdelegates" then get to vote, and again
on any subsequent ballot.


Interestingly, the RNC (at least as of eight years ago) instead just ignores any pledged delegate who doesn't vote for their pledgee on the first ballot.
